# LinkedList like database ORM lite

Tags: java, android, linked-list, ormlite

I'm trying to create (if it possible) an LinkedList like database.

The idea is that the data I add in my table will require to have an complex order structure as when I add a new item, I can add it anywhere in my list.

For example if I have an list with items (1), (2), (3), (4), (5). I can add a new item directly on position (2), thus altering the whole list (or at least the elements following the item on the position (2)).

Another thing I have to consider for this is that every item must know his previous item's ID(not the index, but some custom ID that is gotten from the server). This ID will actually be needed when I have to also re-order the list on the server (when I upload an item, an request for order with the previous id must be sent also).

At this moment, my document model looks something like this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = DocumentsTable.TABLE_NAME, daoClass = DocumentDao.class)
public class Document implements Parcelable {    
@DatabaseField(columnName = DocumentsTable.LOCAL_ID_COLUMN, generatedId = true, dataType = DataType.INTEGER)
    int localId;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = DocumentsTable.SERVER_ID_COLUMN, unique = true, dataType = DataType.STRING, useGetSet = true)
    String serverId;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = DocumentsTable.ALIAS_COLUMN, dataType = DataType.STRING, useGetSet = true)
    String alias;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = DocumentsTable.NAME_COLUMN, dataType = DataType.STRING, useGetSet = true)
    String name;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = DocumentsTable.DESCRIPTION_COLUMN, dataType = DataType.STRING, useGetSet = true)
    String description;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = DocumentsTable.OWNER_COLUMN, dataType = DataType.STRING, useGetSet = true)
    String owner;
...
```

What I am thinking is adding a two new columns, let's call it `prevDoc` & `nextDoc` and set them as Foreig keys. Something like this:

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = DocumentsTable.PREVIOUS_DOC, foreign = true, canBeNull = true)
    Document prevDoc;
@DatabaseField(columnName = DocumentsTable.NEXT_DOC, foreign = true, canBeNull = true)
    Document nextDoc;
```

This way, every item from my table will know what it's previous item should be and what it's next item should be.

**BUT**

Now I'm stuck, at this point, I don't know how can I actually sort this in an correct order. Also, how do I correctly add a new item ?

**New ideas ?**

At this point I think I got on a wrong path and I can't seem to find an good solution. I searched in ORMLite documentation and I found nothing that could help me. Examples for basic linked list like database also didn't help me. I found some graph databases, but I can't use them in Android and they are overkill for what I need.

**LAST CHANCE**
As an ultimate solution, I added a new column, `orderPos`, which I manually update:

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = DocumentsTable.ORDER_POS, dataType = DataType.INTEGER, useGetSet = true)
int orderPos;
```

This is use like this: 
For each item, I set an orderPos value which is incremented at each step.
When I need to add an item to an specific position, I get all the items following that item and increment their orderPos with 1, after which I add the item with the orderPos of the position that I want.
I know this will involve an complexity of O(n-pos) + 1, but I couldn't think of anything else at the moment.

Please let me know what you think and how can I correctly implement something like this on Android using ORMLite.

Answer (score 1):

> This way, every item from my table will know what it's previous item should be and what it's next item should be.

Yeah this is a little strange.  Typically the fields would determine the order and since you are storing the fields, then you would just use the `qb.orderBy(...)` methods to output the list in any order.

> For example if I have an list with items (1), (2), (3), (4), (5). I can add a new item directly on position (2), thus altering the whole list (or at least the elements following the item on the position (2)).

So I assume you insert an item into position 2 but then if you insert another item in position 2, the previous #2 item becomes #3.  Yeah, that's difficult.

> For each item, I set an orderPos value which is incremented at each step. When I need to add an item to an specific position, I get all the items following that item and increment their orderPos with 1, after which I add the item with the orderPos of the position that I want. I know this will involve an complexity of O(n-pos) + 1,

Yep. That sounds about right.  You can do the update in 1 SQL expression so every insert would take 2 SQL operations.  That's not going to be too painful unless there are many rows in your table.

Thinking outside the box, one thing you could do is to use the width of the `Long` value.  The first item in the list gets `Long.MAX_VALUE / 2`.  Whenever you insert into the list, you take the left-hand sort value and the right-hand sort value and take the average of them.  You'd have to find the two values on either side of the one you want to insert which would take 2 queries but you wouldn't need to update all rows.

1. Find row `>=` the row I am inserting.  If none then `Long.MAX_VALUE`.
2. Find the row `<` the row I am inserting.  If none then 0.
3. Average each row's order column.
4. Insert new row.

But I think your position idea may work better for your situation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in the end I decided to go with something else. I use orderPos with an float value and set it to each item. When I need to reorder by adding an item to another position I subtract 0,000001 from that value and set it to the new item.

And when the value is the same I make an median with that value and the one before. This way I don't have to reorder the entire list!

Comment: Cool @IonutNegru.  Yeah, this is similar to my idea around using longs.  Be careful about rounding errors in the floating point space.